Asymptotics of generalized exponents of highest weight modules
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra and  $H^k$ be the space of homogeneous degree $k$ harmonic polynomials in $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ and $H\subset\mathrm{Sym}(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ be all harmonic polynomials. Then for any dominant weight $\lambda$ one has the graded multiplicity
\begin{equation}
F(\lambda)=\sum_{k\geq 0} \dim \hom_\mathfrak{g}( V(\lambda), H^k) t^k,
\end{equation}
where $V(\lambda)$ is the irreducible representation of highest weight $\lambda$. Then Kostant showed that
$$
\dim\hom_{\mathfrak{g}}(V(\lambda), H)=\dim V(\lambda)_0
$$
and the $k$ for which $\dim\hom_\mathfrak{g}(V(\lambda), H^k)\neq 0$ are the generalized exponents of $V(\lambda)$ (recall that exponentiating them essentially gives the eigenvalues of the Coxeter element on $V(\lambda)_0$).
The function
$$
F\colon P^{\mathrm{dom}}\to\mathbb{Z}[t]
$$
is supported near the walls: $F(\lambda)$ is essentially the spherical Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomial $P_{1,\lambda}(t)$ and the periodicity properties of Kazhdan-Lusztig polynomials imply that $$\min\{\ell(\mu)\mid P_{\mu,\lambda}\neq 0\}\to\infty$$
as $\lambda$ tends deeper into the dominant chamber.
Question: What are the asymptotics of $F(\lambda)$ as $\ell(\lambda)\to\infty$ in the affine Weyl group (necessarily near the walls)?
This is then pretty much equivalent to asking about asymptotics of eigenvalues of the Coxeter element on $V(\lambda)_0$ as $\lambda$ is taken longer and near the walls. (It is also phrasable in terms of Kostka-Foulkes polynomials, etc.)
Addendum: Certain walls are easy: $F(\lambda)$ is just a power of $t$ when the Schubert variety in the affine Grassmannian labelled by $\lambda$ is rationally smooth. In type $A$ there are two infinite families of such $\lambda$, running along (parts of) two of the walls. This says nothing nothing for other types as there are only finitely-many rationally-smooth Schubert varieties then.
